# Showing that a set is a basis for the product topology on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R} $

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider the space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ of all functions $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$

For a function $f ∈ \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, a finite set $K ⊆ R$, and a real number $ε > 0$, define $U(f, K, ε) :=\{g ∈ \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}: |g(x) − f(x)| < ε$ for every $x ∈ K$}

Show that the family of all such sets is a basis for the product topology on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$.

My attempt:

$1)$ Take $f(x) = x, g(x) = x + 1, K = [0,1], ε =2$, then $U(x, [0,1], 2) =$ {$|x + 1 - x| < 2$, for all $x \in K$} $=$ {$1<2$, for all $x \in K$}. Hence the first axiom of a basis is satisfied.

$2)$ Let $m \in U_1(f_1,K_1,ε_1)$ $\cap$ $U_2(f_2,K_2,ε_2)$, then $m \in U_1(f_1,K_1,ε_1)$, hence $m = |g_1(x) - f_1(x)| < ε_1$, and $m \in U_2(f_2,K_2,ε_2)$, hence $m = |g_2(x) - f_2(x)| < ε_2$.

Let $|g_3(x) - f_3(x)| := min$ {$|g_1(x) - f_1(x)|, |g_2(x) - f_2(x)|$} and let $ε_3 := min${$ε_1,ε_2$}, then $m = U_3(f_3,K_3,ε_3) =$ {$|g_3(x) - f_3(x)| < ε_3$} $\subset U_1(f_1,K_1,ε_1)$ $\cap$ $U_2(f_2,K_2,ε_2)$.

Hence the second axiom of a basis is satisfied, and therefore, the family of all such sets is a basis for the product topology.

Comment: My edit was to get the def'n of $U(f,K,\varepsilon)$ onto one line.

Answer (score 2):

I’m afraid that none of that makes any sense; it appears that you’ve understood neither the definition of the sets $U(f,K,\epsilon)$ not what has to be done to show that the family of all of those sets is a base for the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$.

First, the set $K$ is required to be a **finite** subset of $\Bbb R$, so it cannot be the interval $[0,1]$, as you’ve attempted to make it in your $(1)$. Secondly, even if that **were** allowed, and $f(x)=x$, $U(f,K,2)$ would be

$$\left\{g\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}:|g(x)-x|<2\text{ for all }x\in[0,1]\right\}\,;$$

this is the set of all real-valued functions on $\Bbb R$ that differ from the function $f(x)=x$ by less than $2$ over the interval $[0,1]$; the two expressions that you equate with it make no sense at all.

In your $(2)$ you first have $m\in U(f_1,K_1,\epsilon_1)\cap U(f_2,K_2,\epsilon_2)$, which means that $m\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$, i.e., that $m$ is a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. But then you say that $m=|g_1(x)-f_1(x)|$, which makes sense only if $m\in\Bbb R$, i.e., if $m$ is a real number. These two statements are absolutely incompatible: $m$ cannot be both a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ and a real number. A further problem with that statement is that nowhere do you define $g_1$.

Finally, you’re trying to prove the wrong thing. The problem is not to show that this collection of sets is a base for **some** topology: the problem is to show that it is a base specifically for the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. To do that you must show that every open set in the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is the union of sets of the form $U(f,K,\epsilon)$. You do this by letting $V$ be an arbitrary non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ and showing that for each $f\in V$ there are a finite $K_f\subseteq\Bbb R$ and an $\epsilon_f>0$ such that $f\in U(f,K_f,\epsilon_f)\subseteq V$.

In order to do this, you have to understand the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. Most likely it’s been defined in terms of a certain base $\mathscr{B}$ whose members are also defined partly in terms of finite subsets of $\Bbb R$. If that is the case, you know that there is a $B_f\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_f\subseteq V$, and you will have to show how to choose $K_f$ and $\epsilon_f$ so that $U(f,K_f,\epsilon_f)\subseteq B$.